# Import User Photo Library Albums

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, photos, alassetslibrary

I am trying to import, not just multiple photos at a time, but also multiple albums (or single if impossible) at a time.

Basically I want to implement something similar to stock Picture Frame App on iPad.  The way it lets you select albums (iPad Settings>Picture Frame).

So far I am under the impression that **UIImagePickerController** is not simply powerful enough for this.  I did find **ALAssetsLibrary** promising, but nothing is successful yet.

All I need is a given NSArray of photos from a given photo album.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[ALAssetsGroupType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**. Its a bitfield to identify types of asset.

```
typedef NSUInteger ALAssetsGroupType;
```

**Availability:** Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**Declared In:** ALAssetsLibrary.h

**Types of Asset**

> ALAssetsGroupLibrary
>
> ALAssetsGroupAlbum
>
> ALAssetsGroupEvent
>
> ALAssetsGroupFaces
>
> ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
>
> ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream
>
> ALAssetsGroupAll

**Example code:**

```
[assetsLibraryObj enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

**ALAssetsGroupLibrary**

The Library group that includes all assets that are synced from iTunes.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupAlbum**

All the albums created on the device or synced from iTunes, not including Photo Stream or Shared Streams

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupEvent**

All events, including those created during Camera Connection Kit import.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupFaces**

All the faces albums synced from iTunes.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos**

All the photos in the Camera Roll.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream**

The PhotoStream album.

In iOS 6.0 and later, this also includes Shared Streams.

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.

**ALAssetsGroupAll**

The same as ORing together all the group types except for ALAssetsGroupLibrary.

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared in ALAssetsLibrary.h.